# Java web service architecture with REST

Tags: java, rest, integration

I am designing a Java web application that will be deployed to the Wildfly or Tomcat (not decided yet).

Basically it's about the offline java application that needs a REST interface for communication (to accept JSON data). The idea is that application runs **all the time** and processes the requests stored in redis cache (where the received JSON data is stored).

I used the Spring MVC framework for a web site in the past but I don't need the MVC pattern for the REST interface.

Is there a way you can point me to for using a Spring framework (or some other Java framework) **to add the capability to recieve a POST requests to the existing offline application**? Or it will be better to just write **the REST service that will use the same cache** as the existing application?

To illustrate my question I am attaching the simplified diagram of the architecture I am looking for:

[image: Existing application and the extension]

Comment: Ok, hold on a second, you need a way to deliver data to an offline network. That's what I understood.

Comment: @WeareBorg: something like that. I need a way to receive a POST request in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers from Andres, ESala and kervin pointed me to the right direction but the solution I found most suitable was:

- implementation of REST services using **Spring MVC** and
- transformation of the main process from the existing application to the **Spring scheduled task**.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you speak of **receiving** a POST request, you are automatically referring to a HTTP server.

The question is just whether that server is running as a service, or on-demand.

> Is there a way you can point me to for using a Spring framework (or some other Java framework) to add the capability to recieve a POST requests to the existing offline application?

Not without introducing some sort of HTTP container, no.

> Or it will be better to just write the REST service that will use the same cache as the existing application?

Yes, exactly.  And as another mentioned, personally I'd stick with Spring MVC.  But Jersey should also work very well for you for your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use any light ESB, like Camel, Mule or Spring Integration. If you have already worked with Spring probably the latter will be the easiest for you.

The purpose of this kind of apps is to facilitate the task of communicating anything with anything (on this case, an HTTP endpoint with your offline app).

Take a look at this:

https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=spring%20integration%20http-inbound

Comment: That looks interesting. I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring MVC for that.

The **M**odel are your domain classes, the **V**iew is JSON in this case, and the **C**ontrollers handle the requests to perform logic operations, business as usual.

You can also take advantage of Spring's `@RestController` annotation to quickly create your endpoints, like in this java example:

```
@RestController
public class MovieController {

    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/movies/{search}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Movie> findMovies(@PathVariable String search) {
        return movieRepository.findByName(search);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/movies", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void postMovie(@RequestBody Movie movie) {
        movieRepository.save(movie);
    }

}
```